# Oracle procedure usage metrics?

Tags: oracle

I'm recently working in a large Oracle database that is in need of cleanup. As part of that cleanup, we'll be looking for unused PL/SQL.

Does Oracle internally track usage of entities over time? If so, how is that information accessed?

Comment: Not an answer, but there was a issue discussed with AskTom (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=usage-analysis-of-stored-procs). So you either have to map session data to object data or turn on auditing. AWR or statspack might help but are not reliable for seldom used procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to tell if a stored procedure is still needed.  You can find when it was last compiled.  Perhaps you can learn something from that date?  No documentation available?  Anything you remove can make a future procedure fail.  Internally, Oracle can show you dependencies, but the problem is with all the different clients.  You could add logging to each and every procedure about which you're in doubt, and come back and see after a couple of years.

Comment: _"come back and see after a couple of years."_   Indeed.  The problem with relying on auditing for something like this is the fact that some procedures may only be used annually - or less.  But even the seldom-used procedures may very well be business critical when they _are_ used.

Comment: @EdStevens, indeed, I had end of year in mind, and then forgot to mention it.  Can you imagine that even nowadays, something as archaic as documentation could come in handy?  No code should go into production without a "paper" trace.

Comment: H Pille - re: documentation, couldn't agree more. I'm one year into retirement after 40 years in IT, starting as a COBOL programmer and ending as an oracle DBA.  Documentation (both writing and reading) has always been one of my soapbox issues.

Comment: Definitely no documentation. It was an acquired system, and the company that wrote the code was focused on getting to a profitable position, so documentation was not a priority. I've never seen a business system that has documentation down to this level. Is that a reality somewhere?

Comment: @GaTechThomas, if you have a DBA worth his salary, he/she wouldn't allow any code into the DB without justification.  Every change can be done by a script, the script can be registered in a SCCS,

Comment: @GerardH.Pille we inherited a difficult situation. We're trying to get there, which was what spawned the question.

Comment: @GaTechThomas, you'll get there, but it'll take it's time.  When you decide to remove something, play safe and store it somewhere.

Comment: FWIW, a couple months after this conversation we extracted all code into a git repo and put in place a CI process (and on the path to CI/CD). Huge improvement for everyone who touches the system.